# Changes to /etc/resolv.conf discarded when connecting to a new network

Tags: networking, 12.10, resolv.conf

I have upgraded to 12.10 from 12.04 recently and I am having issues with connecting to the Internet.

I got an IP address and am able to ping other LAN IPs in the local network but I am unable to connect to the Internet and am even unable to ping www.google.com from a terminal.

Somehow making changes in `/etc/resolv.conf` and restarting `resolvconf` service and rebooting works but I need to do this every time I connect to a new network. How do I make these changes permanent?

Can someone suggest a solution to this issue?

Comment: @medigeek This is incredibly unhelpful. The question is about DNS configuration in Ubuntu, not some intermittent Windows issue. Please take your “restart it and see if it works” comments elsewhere.

Comment: @medigeek no offense, but I absolutely fail to see how a “stuck” network card could affect DNS resolution. Even if it did, you advise shutting down _all_ routers and modems? Really?

Answer (score 2):

As per the header on /etc/resolv.conf:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Try putting your change in

/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base and they should get added to /etc/resolv.conf when it gets re-written every 15 minutes.

Comment: It is not true that /etc/resolv.conf gets rewritten every fifteen minutes. When resolvconf is installed and /etc/resolv.conf is a symbolic link to /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf, the target of /etc/resolv.conf can get rewritten when resolvconf's nameserver information changes, generally as a result of some change in network configuration.

Comment: Putting nameserver information in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base is at best a workaround for the problem. Workarounds are good but a solution to the real problem would be better.

Comment: @jdthood It's not a workaround, it's how it's been done for years

Comment: Nameserver information (addresses, search domain names) should be added to /etc/network/interfaces if you are using ifup to configure network interfaces. Nameserver information should be entered into the NetworkManager connections editor if you are using NM to configure interfaces. The only thing that really belongs in /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base is resolver options such as `timeout` or `ndots`.

Answer (score 1):

> ***DISCLAIMER!***  Following this answer may cause unexpected problems if your DNS servers are managed as a part of network manager - while this will force the usage of the DNS servers you want above the `dnsmasq` system and the DNS servers in network manager's settings, it will do this for *everything*.  As well, certain networks and/or connections may *require* you to use **their** DNS server(s) to get out to the internet with resolving things.

Edit `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and add the `nameserver 1.2.3.4` record here.

This works on 14.04 even on a Desktop install.  I know this because I have a locally running DNS server (via `bind9`) on my laptop locally for local zone resolution (since I do a lot of virtual machine stuff), and it becomes necessary to query my local DNS first above all else.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic procedure which fixes a couple of known bugs in nameserver information handling.

Is resolvconf installed?  If so then do the following.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

If it is not installed then do the following.

```
sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

Now that resolvconf is installed correctly, reboot so that resolvconf will be provided with nameserver information.

If name service is still broken and you are using NetworkManager to manage networking then open /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf in an editor and comment out the line "dns=dnsmasq". To comment it out, put a '#' character at the beginning of the line.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Next go into the connection editor and make sure that the connection you are using is properly configured. E.g., most often "network indicator | Edit Connections... | Wired | Wired connection 1 | Edit... | IPv4 Settings | Method" is set to "Automatic (DHCP)" and no "Additional DNS server" addresses are set.

Then restart network-manager.

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

Now confirm that the expected nameserver address(es) appear in /etc/resolv.conf.

If you aren't using NetworkManager to configure interfaces and you are using `ifup` then edit `/etc/network/interfaces` and include `dns-nameservers` and `dns-search` lines in the appropriate `iface` stanza as needed.  Make sure that /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head only contains comment lines and that /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base and /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail are absent or empty.  Then `ifdown` and `ifup` the interface. Confirm that the nameserver address(es) that you added to /etc/network/interfaces now appear in /etc/resolv.conf.

If name service still does not work then there's most likely a local problem: a misconfigured DHCP server, for example. Another known cause of problems is third-party VPN clients which trash the symbolic link /etc/resolv.conf. If your LAN seems OK and you aren't using third-party networking software then file a bug report against NetworkManager or resolvconf, whichever you think is more likely the culprit.

Comment: This is no longer the case - `dnsmasq` is what `/etc/resolv.conf` looks at (127.0.1.1) in a default install (since at least 14.04)

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with dns myself and have posted a [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/542922/295286) and solution to it, which lists some of the ways you can change dns settings. Basically, there are two ways - either edit any of 3 files in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/` or edit `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. I personally prefer the first one.

Bellow are some of the methods i apply to my ubuntu and linux mint systems. Use at your discression.

**/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf**

I will start with this since others have covered already resolv.conf  files. What you see bellow is portion of this file. Look at line 18, which says `prepent name server` . It will add your specified dns to the settings, no matter what connection you use.

> 1  # Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient, which is included in
>   Debian's
>
> ```
>  2  #       dhcp3-client package.
>  3  #
>  4  # This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
>  5  #       man page for more information about the syntax of this file
>  6  #       and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
>  7  #       dhclient.
>  8  #
>  9  # Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
> 10  #       not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
> 11  #       few changes must be made to this file, if any.
> 12  #
>
> 13  option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
>
> 14  #send host-name "andare.fugue.com";
> 15  send host-name = gethostname();
> 16  #send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
> 17  #send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
> 18  #supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
> 19  #prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
> 20  prepend domain-name-servers 208.67.220.220;
> 21  request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
> 22          domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
> 23          dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
> 24          netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
> 25          rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
> 26          dhcp6.fqdn, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
> 27  #require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
> 28  #timeout 60;
> 29  #retry 60;
> 30  #reboot 10;
> 31  #select-timeout 5;
> 32  #initial-interval 2;
> 33  #script "/etc/dhcp3/dhclient-script";
> 34  #media "-link0 -link1 -link2", "link0 link1";
> 35  #reject 192.33.137.209;
>
> 36  #alias {
> 37  #  interface "eth0";
> ```

**/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/**

The text from either of 3 will be added to `/etc/resolv.conf`, so I don't think it matters which one you choose. I'd use `tail`, personally. Simply open it with any text editor and add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` , where 8.8.8.8 is google's public dns but you can use whatever dns you like.

**A small tip**

In `/etc/Network-Manager/Network-Manager.conf` I suggest you comment out `dns=dnsmasq` line, which is a plugin for network manager, which goes automatically to the nearest/easiest to reach dns, which might not be what you want, if you want to by pass the network's dns, and use your own.

**Side note:** The fact that resolv.conf gets rewritten is actually normal - it does so upon every new connection on my machine as well. While I can't answer why, my guess is that NetworkManager gets dhcp lease from the local connection, and uses that local connection's settings, dns, and whatever else, so resolv.conf needs to be adapted to that.